# How to override TokenValidationParameters.SignatureValidator, look at a condition and fallback on default behavior if the conditon isn't met?

Tags: .net, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I'm doing a .Net 6 API and I'm playing with JWT tokens right now for authentication/authorization.

For automatic test purposes, I want to allow a secure backdoor. The backdoor in question is that if the token has a certain issuer (which is only known by the company), we skip the signature validation. To be even more secure, we have a flag to activate and deactivate this feature and it will only be activated on the test environment with fake data.

However, we also have analysts that use the test environment to do manual testing and they use real JWT using Azure B2C. For those, we want to verify the signature and makes sure it is valid (normal platform behavior).

We would prefer not to add another authentication scheme because all the routes in the API have a specified scheme and we want this behavior to work without having to change any of that.

This is what we tried inside the `AddJwtBearer` method:

`...`

```
tokenValidationParameters.SignatureValidator = (string token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) =>
{
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var securityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
    if (securityToken.Issuer == testAutoFakeTokenSection.GetValue<string>("Issuer"))
    {
        return securityToken;
    }

    // For tokens not issued by "test", fall back to default validation behavior
    handler.ValidateToken(token, defaultTokenValidationParameters(), out var validatedToken);
    return validatedToken;
};
```

`...`

If we don't override the SignatureValidator, the normal authentication works fine. The solution above works great to authenticate Fake test JWTs with the fake issuer. However, when comes real JWTs, we would like to rollback to the default SignatureValidator (just like if we didn't override it). We can't seem to do that.

Also, the reason why we look at the issuer inside this delegate is because we don't have access to the token's issuer outside of it to verify if we let the user pass or if we challenge the token.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

This seems **EXTREMELY** dangerous.

What if a malicious user knew this "test" issuer and used it to gain unauthorised access to your application...?

However, if I was to implement this, I'd make use of a the conditional compilation directive:

```cs
#if DEBUG
    tokenValidationParameters.SignatureValidator = (string token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) =>
    {
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var securityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
        if (securityToken.Issuer == testAutoFakeTokenSection.GetValue<string>("Issuer"))
        {
            return securityToken;
        }

        // For tokens not issued by "test", fall back to default validation behavior
        handler.ValidateToken(token, defaultTokenValidationParameters(), out var validatedToken);
        return validatedToken;
    };
#endif
```

Note: I'm wrapping the whole `SignatureValidator` override here as somethings are best left to the underlying package.

Or, an environment variable:

```cs
if (System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Environment") == "AuthTests")
{
    tokenValidationParameters.SignatureValidator = (string token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) =>
    {
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var securityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
        if (securityToken.Issuer == testAutoFakeTokenSection.GetValue<string>("Issuer"))
        {
            return securityToken;
        }

        // For tokens not issued by "test", fall back to default validation behavior
        handler.ValidateToken(token, defaultTokenValidationParameters(), out var validatedToken);
        return validatedToken;
    };
}
```

Note: this would require you setting your `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `AuthTests`.

I prefer the former as the code when built in `Release` will not include the code overriding your token validation at all.

Comment: It is only in test environment and with fake data. No danger here. I don't see why it would be more dangerous than using an API Key (that's what I put in the issuer!). However, your solution doesn't solve the problem. I want to be able to use the real authentication if I have a real issuer. You just put a conditional on the environment, which I already did.